# enviar multiples peticiones usando useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

existe una manera de enviar multiples peticiones usando useEffect, este es mi codigo pero solo me recibe una peticion y si recibo los elementos en la consola, pero el response solo me llega el primero y nunca realiza la segunda peticion

```
const [consultaLista, guardarConsultaList] = useState(false);
const [arrayList, saveArrayList] = useState([]);
const [resultsuccess, savaeResultSuccess] = useState([]);

export const codeAction =async (list, dispatch)=>{
    
    const promiseCodes = HttpClient.get(`/URL/${list}`);

    return await Promise.all([promiseCodes]);

}

useEffect(() => {
            arrayList.map(elements => (
                codeAction(elements, dispatch).then(response => {
                    console.log('result elemetns', elements)
                    console.log('response', response);
                })
            ))
        
        //consultApi;
    }, [consultaLista])
```

usando onClick hice esto pero me guarda dos veces el mismo resultado

```
    let newData = arrayList.map((elements, index) => {
                <div key={index}>
                    {codeAction(elements, dispatch).then(response => {
                        savaeResultSuccess([...response, response]);
//y de esta manera solo me guarda un elemento + el segundo response, pero no el response de la primera perticion
//ejemplo envio dos id, 1223, 1244 y el resultado seria esto, "1","2","2","3", data: 1244....                         
//savaeResultSuccess([...elements, response]);

                    })}
                </div>
    
            })
            console.log('response datas form', newData)
    
            savaeResultSuccess(newData)
```

[image: Response onclick]

Comment: Crea una variable que reciba cada petición _esperando_ la respuesta con un `await` dentro de tu `map` y coméntanos que lograste

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera te refieres a esto?   `const response = await codeAction(elements, dispatch)`, si hablas de esto, me da error porque el await ya lo hice en la promesa, este es el error `'await' is only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que debes poder convertir tu loop asincrono antes de esperar la respuesta. Trata de hacer esto -> `arrayList.map(async element => {/..../})`

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera si, me faltaba el async, lo hice de esta manera, pero obtengo el mismo resultado `const newData = arrayList.map(async (elements, index) => {const result = await  codeAction(elements, dispatch).then(response => { return response; })savaeResultSuccess([...result, result])console.log('result ',result) })` y si solo guardo la peticion de esta manera`savaeResultSuccess([ result])` no me guarda los dos, reemplaza el primer resultado por el segundo, es decir solo se guarda el segundo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acabo de solucionar mi problema, espero que alguien le sirva o pueda mejorarlo

```
//este es mi codigo en el cual mando a llamar los datos de mi api 
export const codeAction = async (list, dispatch) => {
        const datasAcces = list.map(async elements => {
            if (elements !== "") {
                return await HttpClient.get(`/URL/${elements}`);
            }
        });
        return await Promise.all(datasAcces);
    
    }



//state para guardar la consulta
    const [consultaLista, guardarConsultaList] = useState(false);
    //posible state para guardar el array de la lista de checklist
    const [arrayList, savarArrayList] = useState([]);
    //state para los guardar los resultados de success 200
    const [resultsuccess, savaeResultSuccess] = useState({});
    //para guaardar resultado de badrequest
    const [resultbadrequest, savaeResultBadRequest] = useState({});
```

en mi caso lo hice usando useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (consultaLista) {
            const datas = codeAction(arrayList, dispatch).
                then(response => { 
                    savaeResultSuccess(response); 
                }).catch(error =>{
                    savaeResultBadRequest(error.response);
                });
            guardarConsultaList(false);
            guardarLista({ status: '[ Finish Testing ... ]', list: '' });

        }
    }, [consultaLista])
```

el resultado lo envie a otro componente para poder mapear la data

```
  <ComponenetResultTable
      resultsuccess={resultsuccess}
      resultbadrequest={resultbadrequest}
  />
```

mapeo los resultados para enviarlo a otro component

```
 {Object.keys(resultsuccess).map((codesData, index) => (

   <ResultTable
   key={index}
   resultsuccess={resultsuccess[codesData].data} />
))}
```